# How to manage Test Scenarios in testlink?

Tags: manual-testing, testlink

It's hard to understand how to handle test scenarios in testlink. we always hearing around,
 - one test scenario may consist of many test cases 
 - one test case may include in many test scenarios (test case reusability).

in testlink, how we manage test scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, will this answer fulfill your question, but will give a workaround.
In **TestLink** - you can add 'Test Scenario' as customized field, so that you can see a '**Scenario**' field in Preconditions of Test case.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think adding customized field not the solution for test case reusability. i was thinking how to do it without creating duplicate test cases. in other hand without defining another field we can add the scenario details to the test case title then.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have used testlink, but have you considered trying to use the keywords feature to manage your scenarios?

I believe each test case can have multiple keywords assigned and each keyword can be used on any number of test cases.

You could prefix the keywords with "Scenario-" to make them manageable along with your other keywords.